# How to create JPA query that simultaneously searches in main table rows and in child rows with relation OneToMany

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities. One of them is a child of the other one with a relation with OneToMany. Is it possible to implement search criteria that looks up simultaneously in both the main entity and all the child entities?

Example:
 I have a Company with many employees. If I search with some text, I want to retrieve all the companies, which title contains that text or its employee's names contain that text.

Here are the example entities:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String companyName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “company”, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    protected Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = “company_id”, nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Company company;
}
```

Here is the example query, that does not work :(

```
@Query(value = “SELECT c from Company c WHERE c.companyName LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%') or (SELECT e from c.employees e WHERE e.firstName  LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%')  OR  e.lastName  LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%'))”)
List<Company> findByText( @Param(“text” String text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is a left join here:

```
@Query(value = “SELECT c from Company c left outer join c.employees e 
                WHERE c.companyName LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%') 
                  or e.firstName  LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%')  
                  or  e.lastName  LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%')”)
```

Comment: This way if one company has more than one employee with name, that matches the search filter, it will return that record multiple times

Comment: Use Set instead of List. Just remember to have equals and hashCode implemented

Comment: While running the project the following exception occurs:`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'imageController' defined in file ... nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to have one of the following return types! [interface java.util.List, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Slice, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page]`

Comment: Currently sets are not allowed by the JPA, but with `distinct` it works